# Can't open excel file generated with excelLibrary

Tags: c#, excel, excellibrary

I'm using [excelLibrary](http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/) to programatically create excel files but I get a file format error when I try to open the generated files in Microsoft Office Excel.

I've seen [this has been reported](http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/issues/detail?id=78) but there's still no answer about it.

I use Office 2010 and I'm able to open any other .xls (97-2003 file format) but the ones generated with excelLibrary. I've also tried Open Office and still can't open the generated file. I haven't tried to open them in Office 97-2003.

Just try the [sample code](http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/) to reproduce the error.

Have anybody found how to use the library and not run into this problem?

Comment: Not sure about the error however the library doesnt have 2007 / 2010 support, perhaps look at something newer? http://netoffice.codeplex.com/

Comment: I've found a solution, see my new answer.

Comment: Try [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com). It requireds .NET 3.5 but is awesome and very powerful. It uses OpenOfficeXml.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Found a solution :

```
string filename = "c:\Test.xls";
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
Worksheet sheet = new Worksheet("Test")
workbook.Worksheets.Add(sheet)

for(int i = 0;i < 100; i++)
      sheet.Cells[i,0] = new Cell("");

workbook.save(filename);
```

> The problem is that Office 2010 doesn't support it unless there are
>   100 or more Cells Filled.
>
> My work around was to have it fill 100 cells in a for loop with "". 
>   That way it gets it's 100 cell count in and then it works just fine.

Reference : [here](http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/issues/detail?id=78)

Comment: That worked!  But the 256 column limit is just too restrictive (Excel 97?)  Too bad, I really prefer LGPL license over Apache.   Trying out NPOI below.

Comment: you are my hero

Comment: This is very strange. Why does Office 2010 requires at least 100 cells in a .xls file? Can a .xls file with less than 100 cells be opened in earlier versions of Office, like Office 2003?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately excel file exported with excelLibrary are not compatible with office 2010 Excel, this is an already reported issue but seems that the library development is no longer active .

I've switched to [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) .

Comment: +1 for NPOI, just be aware that NPOI API is pretty verbose in style, requiring you to constantly Create* stuff, in particular when it comes to formatting. Also, their name abbreviations are truly awful, making intellisense nearly useless until you remember that the thing you want is called "HSSF".

Comment: Yes. Try [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com). It requireds .NET 3.5 but is awesome and very powerful. It uses OpenOfficeXml.

Answer (score -1):

Since the sheet name is not given properly, it was throwing that error.

Once we give the sheet a name, it will work properly.