# ExcelLibrary Producing Unreadable Files

Tags: c#, excellibrary

this is my first time using ExcelLibrary and I seem to have run into a little problem. I am saving a test file using the following code:

```
            Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
            Worksheet worksheet = new Worksheet("Sheet 1");

            //Write the first row
            worksheet.Cells[0, 0] = new Cell("Name");
            worksheet.Cells[0, 1] = new Cell("Address");
            worksheet.Cells[0, 2] = new Cell("Phone");
            worksheet.Cells[0, 3] = new Cell("Fax");
            worksheet.Cells[0, 4] = new Cell("E-mail");
            worksheet.Cells[0, 5] = new Cell("Contact Person/s");
            worksheet.Cells[0, 6] = new Cell("Domain/s of Activity");
            worksheet.Cells[0, 7] = new Cell("Number of Employees");
            worksheet.Cells[0, 8] = new Cell("Turnover");
            workbook.Worksheets.Add(worksheet);
            workbook.Save(sfd.FileName);
```

But when I try to open the file, I get a warning box saying it is unreadable. I am opening the file in Excel 2010 and just as a side note, I can open other .xls files just not the ones generated by the program.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't open excel file generated with excelLibrary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107610/cant-open-excel-file-generated-with-excellibrary)

Comment: Repeat of 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107610/cant-open-excel-file-generated-with-excellibrary