# Altering spreadsheet causes loss of formatting

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I use [excellibrary](http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/) library in working with excel. My code is

```
        Workbook book = Workbook.Load(book_name);
        Workbook book_new = Workbook.Load(file_name);

        Worksheet sheet = book.Worksheets[0];
        Worksheet sheet_new = book_new.Worksheets[0];

        for (int rowIndex = 7; rowIndex <= 2235; rowIndex++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sheet.Cells[rowIndex, ost_index] + " " + sheet_new.Cells[rowIndex, ost_index]);

            sheet.Cells[rowIndex, ost_index] = sheet_new.Cells[rowIndex, ost_index];
            sheet.Cells[rowIndex, price_index] = sheet_new.Cells[rowIndex, price_index];
        }

        book.Save(book_name);
```

In this code I copy two cols from one file to another. And there is a problem. this excel file has a lot of style like hyperlink etc. When I open the file after using program I see a window with the text *Unable to read file*. After clicking "ok... ok... ok..." I see file without formatting(no color, no style and so on). How can I repair it?
P.S. sorry for my English.

Comment: you are saving the book..but where are you closing and disposing of the created objects..?

Comment: can you write how to do this?

Comment: you have the code write there in front of you are you familiar with how to debug and use the `Intellesense`

Comment: Excuse me, but I don't understand: which object should i close and dispouse here?

Comment: do you have a method Workbook.Close() or dispose ? call it for both instances of Workbook after the save call.

Comment: I try to open xls file after closing program. And closing there is nothing here as I thing, isn't it?

Comment: "ExcelLibrary.SpreadSheet.Workbook" does not contain a definition for "Close"

Comment: are you using Microsoft.Interop..? the objects are disposed differently also there are examples on the internet.. I would respectfully suggest a simple google search ... and any object that you create an instance of you should be nulling out or disposing or releasing etc...

Comment: But I can't disposed this objects becouse ".Close()" isn't work and I know nothing about this library. Maybe you can suggest me another library for excel? Or help in what should I write to close it. Sorry for my programming level. I just learning.

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107610/cant-open-excel-file-generated-with-excellibrary   I would suggest looking for another library, the one you are using hasn't been updated for a long time now

Comment: Okay, I gonna use newer library if i find it. Thank you for advice

Comment: sheet.Cell[...].Value = sheet_new.Cells[...].Value;

Comment: sheet.Cell[...].Value = sheet_new.Cells[...].Value; it isn't work. I gonna find new library. Big thanks to Shekhar. Can somebody recommend me a library? I would be very grateful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a known [bug](https://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/issues/detail?id=37) in the library, and since the library hasn't been updated since the reporting, your best bet at this point is to switch to another library.